# What is the remainder when the product of the primes between 1 and 100 is divided by 16?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The product of all the prime numbers between 1 and 100 is equal to $P$. What is the remainder when $P$ is divided by 16?

I have no idea how to solve this, any answers?

Comment: There are only $25$ primes up to $100$.   List them, take their remainders mod $16$, and start multiplying....

Comment: Please don't give your questions uninformative titles like "number theory quickie."

Comment: Thanks, Barry Cipra!  I thought of that too, but is there a quicker way?

Comment: If you give the level of math you're currently in, solving this question would be easier. Are you looking for a pen and paper solution in an introductory algebra class? Or beginning an elementary number theory course and just don't know the terminology? More detail would make this an easy solution.

Comment: Quickest way?  Use a Computer Algebra System, or   http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primorial%28primePi[100]%29+mod+16

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Skip the first prime $2$ and look for the product modulo $8$.
The twenty-four odd primes $<100$ are
$$3,5,7,11,13,17,  19,23,29,31,37,41,  43,47,53,59,61,67, 71,73,79,83,89,97. $$
Modulo $8$, these are
$$3,5,7,3,5,1,3,7,5,7,5,1,3,7,5,3,5,3,7,1,7,3,1,1$$
so their product is $$1^53^75^67^6\equiv 3\pmod 8 $$
(where we might profit from using $x^2\equiv 1\pmod 8$ for odd $x$).
Thus $P\equiv 6\pmod{16}$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a step in logic here.  For example if the remainder mod 16 were 13, the remainder mod 8 would be 5.  You say the answer is 6; how do you know it's not 14?

Comment: @Wildcard Let me try this. The remainder of (3..97) mod 8 is 3, so mod 16 it could be 3 or 11. Multiply either 3 or 11 by the final prime, 2, and in both cases the result is 6 mod 16.

Comment: @Wildcard $\ P/2 = 3+8k\ $ so $\ P = 2(P/2) = 2(3+8k) = 6+16k\ \ $

Answer (score 10):

If the product of the odd primes is $8k+r$ then the product of all of them is $16+2r$. So we only need to work $\bmod 8$. We only need to find primes with residues $3,5$ and $7$. We do it as follows:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 && 5 && 7\\
11 && 13 && 15 \\
19 && 21 && 23\\
27 && 29 && 31\\
35 && 37 && 39\\
43 && 45 && 47\\
51 && 53 && 55\\
59 && 61 && 63\\
67 && 69 && 71\\
75 && 77 && 79\\
83 && 85 && 87\\
91 && 93 && 95\\
99\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then take out non-prime multiples of $3,5,7$

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 && 5 && 7\\
11 && 13 && \cancel{15} \\
19 && \cancel{21} && 23\\
\cancel{27} && 29 && 31\\
\cancel{35} && 37 && \cancel{39}\\
43 && \cancel{45} && 47\\
\cancel{51} && 53 && \cancel{55}\\
59 && 61 && \cancel{63}\\
67 && \cancel{69} && 71\\
\cancel{75} && \cancel{77} && 79\\
83 && \cancel{85} && \cancel{87}\\
\cancel{91} && \cancel{93} && \cancel{95}\\
\cancel{99}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The only column with an odd number of remaining elements is $3\bmod 8$, so the answer is $6$

Comment: I did not immediately see why an odd number of factors is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

- The primes will be $2, \pm 3, \pm 5, \pm 7$ mod $16$.
- $3 \cdot 5 = 15 \equiv -1$ mod $16$.
- $7 \cdot 7 = 49 \equiv 1$ mod $16$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is another way, if you don't mind using the computer.

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 
61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
import operator
import functools
ptot = functools.reduce(operator.mul, primes, 1)
print ptot/16
```

Yay python! It just multiplies all the numbers in the list together, puts it in a variable, divides that variable by 16, prints it, etc. As for the result, you get to compile it with an online compiler to find out.

Or, you know, you could do it the boring way and multiply it all and divide it with google/a calculator's help. But python is much cooler.

**Edit:**

Thanks to user2357112 for commenting that the OP wanted the remainder. In that case, you would use very similar code, but using the % operator instead of a normal divide:

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 
61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
import operator
import functools
ptot = functools.reduce(operator.mul, primes, 1)
print ptot%16
```

giving, of course, 6.

Comment: I love your enthusiasm!  Have you checked out [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net)?   If you haven't, you might enjoy the challenge.  (And I agree: Python is cool!)

Comment: @John, yeah, I've checked out project Euler, I'm on the third problem (I started two days ago because someone recommended it on this website). It's awesome. Thanks!

Comment: We're looking for the remainder, not the quotient.

Comment: @user2357112, thanks for pointing that out! I updated it.